# Can't set the background of ExpandableListView's children programmatically

Tags: android, switch-statement, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView where I want each child to show a different background, depending on the group and child position. So far, I am doing it from the Adapter activity, in the @Override getChildView

Here is a sample of my code

```
        @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);



    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
switch (groupPosition) {
        case 0:
            switch(childPosition){ //
                case 0:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.a1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.a2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.a3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.a4);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            switch(childPosition){
                case 0:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.b1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.b2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.b3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.b4);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch(childPosition)
                case 0:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.c1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.c2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.c3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.c4);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
```

Now, the problem is that, when I open the second (#1), third (#2) group parent, the children are coloured like in the first (#0) Group.

this switches framework was working greatly and, of course, all the colours in "@color" are different from each other.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set background colors when creating the view. Since listviews recycle views, the color does not change when views are re-used.

Comment: Merci Guillaume. Actually it's an ExpListView.
Can you foresee any idea for this issue?

Comment: Change the color outside of the "if (convertView == null)" block

Comment: Merci encore, Guillaume. I put all the switches between the
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
and the
            if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

and it crashes. Actually I had thought of it also earlier on. Any idea?

Comment: If you do it before the said bloc you are going to have NullPointerExceptions when the convertView is not created. You need to do any operation on the list item view after creating the view!

Comment: oh you are right Guillaume, sorry, I don't know what I was thinking!

I edited the text and extracted the switches from the IF statement, but still all the groups have the same background color, I don't get why

Comment: ça c'est tout, merci encore, Guillauma!